# What's so special about 1:03?

Tags: lyrics, meaning

In the song death bed (coffee for your head), there is the following line:

> And sneak out through your kitchen at exactly 1:03

What's the significance of this time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Powfu explained the lyric on *Genius*.

> [I feel like a common curfew for people is midnight. So I was like, I have to make it past midnight, otherwise, it’s not anything. And then three rhymes so I was like, let’s do 1:03.](https://genius.com/19216917)

Comment: Perfect, thanks! As Powfu added this as comment on existing lyrics page it was hard to spot at first but now it's all clear.